# Reason to cast both num and denom for division?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is precision the reason I should cast both num and denominator as decimal so that it returns a decimal? And why does the first & second statement bring different precisions? Both only cast one part.

And instead of casting both to `decimal(12,4)`, why just not cast the denominator to a higher precision?

For example:

```
select 3/cast(2 as decimal(12,4))
select cast(3 as decimal(12,4))/2
select cast(3 as decimal(12,4))/cast(2 as decimal(12,4))
select 3/cast(2 as decimal(16,4))

RETURNS
1.5000000000000
1.500000
1.50000000000000000
1.50000000000000000
```

Comment: Note that if you just want a decimal, `SELECT 3.0 / 2` will give you one, no need for casting. And if you want to know why division gives you a higher precision than you might expect, [that's documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190476).

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Precision, Scale, and Length

Precision is the number of digits in a number.

Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number.

For example, the number `123.45` has a precision of `5` and a scale of `2`.

The following table defines how the precision and scale of the result are calculated when the result of an operation is of type decimal. The result is decimal when either of the following is true:

- Both expressions are decimal.
- One expression is decimal and the other is a data type with a lower precedence than decimal.

The operand expressions are denoted as expression `e1`, with precision `p1` and scale `s1`, and expression `e2`, with precision `p2` and scale `s2`.

The precision and scale for any expression that is not decimal is the precision and scale defined for the data type of the expression.

```
Operation   ||  Result precision                    ||  Result scale 
 e1 + e2    ||  max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1 ||  max(s1, s2)
 e1 - e2    ||  max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1 ||  max(s1, s2)
 e1 * e2    ||  p1 + p2 + 1                         ||  s1 + s2
 e1 / e2    ||  p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)  ||  max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
 e1 % e2    ||  min(p1-s1, p2 -s2) + max( s1,s2 )   ||  max(s1, s2)
```

You can read more in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)